# Canvas App display only SEVERAL web apps with specified URL

Tags: canvas, app

I faced with such issue, that canvas app displays web applications not from all specified URLs (I use visualforce page to display canvasApp). For example, i can't display facebook.com main page, but i can display Jira home page. What could be causing such a problem? How might I investigate and resolve this issue?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to display another site inside a frame or iframe. There is a way to forbid this using the HTTP-Header `X-Frame-Options`, which is set to `DENY` on facebook.com for example. So this site cannot be displayed in a frame as facebook doesn't like you to do so.

However, there is a dirty workaround for this, which **SHOULD NOT** be used. This includes proxying the website through a reverse proxy like nginx and removing the `X-Frame-Options` header.

More information can be found in the [Open Web Application Security Project - Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Defending_with_X-Frame-Options_Response_Headers).